# how can I search in TWO columns if key1 in column1 is equal to value1 and key2 is equal to value2 in column2 using MYSQL MARIADB?

Tags: mysql, json, laravel, mariadb

one column works

```
whereJsonContains('VehicleApplications'
        ,['ModelName' => $model, 'YearID' => $year] )->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you define your variable types if someone knows of a cleaner query post it

```
    $make       = (string) $make;
    $model      = (string) $model;
    $year       = (int) $year;
    $category   = (int) $category;

    whereJsonContains('VehicleApplications',
        ['ModelName' => $model, 'YearID' => $year]
    )->
    whereJsonContains('pcItems',
        ['pcCategoryID' => $category]
    )->paginate(10);
```